# Discrepancy of torch shape function for 1 dimensional shaped tensor

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor, torch

I am confused by the behavior of `torch`'s `shape` function. When a tensor `t` has shape say, `[3,2]`, then assigning `N, M = t.shape` gives `N = 3` and `M = 2`. Whereas if a tensor `t` has shape `[3]`, assigning `X = t.shape` evaluates `X = torch.Size([3])`. Why this discrepancy? Why do I need to do `X = t.shape[0]` to get `X =3`?

```
>>> t
tensor([[2.0000, 1.5000],
        [5.5000, 5.0000],
        [3.0000, 2.0000]])
>>> t.shape
torch.Size([3, 2])
>>> N, M = t.shape
>>> N
3
>>> M
2
>>> torch.tensor([1, 1.5, 0.5]).shape
torch.Size([3])
>>> X = torch.tensor([1, 1.5, 0.5]).shape
>>> X
torch.Size([3])
```

Answer (score 0):

A valid point but you can also get the 3 by doing this

```
>>> X, = torch.tensor([1, 1.5, 0.5]).shape
>>> X
3
```

Comment: alternatively with `shape[0]` or `size(0)`.